# Can I create a folder under favorites that contains all emails of a particular category?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook categories fairly frequently for categorizing emails.

Its important to note that even though multiple emails might have the same category, they may be stored in different folders.

It would be very useful to be able to have a virtual folder in the `Favorites` section that would show all emails with the same category but I can't seem to find out how to do this.

Is there another way to have a view of all emails with the same category without doing a search each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display categories in Outlook's sidebar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1228870/how-can-i-display-categories-in-outlooks-sidebar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Search Folder and add to Favorites

1. Right-click on "Search Folders" in the folder list
2. Click "New Search Folder..."
3. Select "Categorized Mail" under "Organizing Mail"
4. Choose categories
5. Click OK to create the folder
6. Drag the new Search Folder to your Favorite Folders section